# Evaluation of integral with residue theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bbqD.png)

[image]

I tried to solve this integral using the residue theorem but wolframalpha says it's incorrect, and I can't find any mistakes in my algebra, so I'm wondering where I messed up. Wolframalpha says the residual should be what I have but with -27 instead of -36

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be trying to evaluate the residue at $\;z=3i\;$ ...but the limit that you wrote above is *not* the way to do it as that is a pole of order **two**, so the correct way to do it is with

$$\lim_{z\to3i}\left[(z-3i)^2\frac{e^{iz}}{(z-3i)^2(z+3i)^2}\right]'$$

Give it a try now...

Comment: In case you want to be sure, the residue is $$-\frac i{27e^3}=\frac1{27\,i\,e^3}$$

Comment: Thank you so much! how do you figure out what order a pole is?

Comment: It is just like the order of singularities of rational functions, or order of roots of a polynomial...in this case, if $\;f(z)\;$ is our function, observe that $\;(z-3i)^2 f(z)\;$ has no singularity at all at $\;z=3i\;$ , and $\;2\;$ is the minimal power of $\;z-3i\;$ for which this happens...These are standard definitions in complex analysis, in particular in residues calculus and complex integration.